# MySQL Query in 3 Tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a MySQL query to give me related data 2 tables away. So one user would have access to 2 projects, with a total of 3 posts (in "stream"). Essentially, I want to get the associated projects in project_users and then get posts in stream associated those projects.

**The data looks something like this:**

Table 1: user (1 user identified by 'id')

Table 2: project_users (user associated with 2 projects in this case)

Table 3: stream (posts attached to different projects, but I should get 3 based on my test data set)

**My (broken) query looks like this:**

```
SELECT U.`id`, P.`kf_users`, P.`kf_projects`, S.`kf_projects`, S.`body`
    FROM users U
    LEFT JOIN projects_users P ON U.`id` = P.`kf_users`
    LEFT JOIN stream S ON P.`kf_users` = S.`kf_projects`
    WHERE U.`id` = 1
```

What on earth am I missing? I tried subqueries, but it wouldn't let me have multiple rows in it, rendering it useless in the form I had it.

Thanks!

Comment: is `U.kp_user` in the `WHERE` clause the correct column (not supposed to just be `U.id`)? (I don't have a schema, so this is just a guess.)

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. Still no luck though!

Comment: You need to provide the schema. How is the query broken?

Comment: @Rylan: Any specific errors you're getting back, or just not the correct information. Also, are you sure you want `LEFT JOIN`s? (I assume you want the ability to query information that may not have a link).

Comment: I'm assuming that u.id is a number ( and the number 1 actually exists ). If it's not numeric you shouldn't rely on the implicit character conversion. It can cause nastiness.

Comment: @BradChristie I get no results any time I try this query.

Comment: Is it S.`kf_project` or S.`kf_projects` (with an `s`)?  Also, why is `project_users` linked to `stream` via field `kf_users` = `kf_projects`?  Those don't sound like the same field.  I've made that change and used some sample data to test here, works just fine: http://www.sqlize.com/1fkI5N4ekW

Comment: @mellamokb Thanks for catching that as well. What a fail of a first question :(

Comment: @RylanDirksen: It's only a fail if you don't learn from it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get no results any time I try this query

Really?! Then try changing it to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users U
WHERE id = 1
```

I suspect that will give you no results too. Knowing that this query also fails should hopefully help you to find the problem more quickly (you don't have a user with id 1).

Note: If this gives you a result, then the query you posted above with the LEFT JOIN should return some rows too, because adding a LEFT JOIN shouldn't remove any rows.

---

*Update*: Try adding aliases to make the column names unique:

```
SELECT
    U.id,
    P.kf_users,
    P.kf_projects AS p_kf_projects,
    S.kf_projects AS s_kf_projects,
    S.body
FROM ....
```

Comment: Definitely got a result for the query you gave. I also joined it to the projects_users table and got results. (SELECT U.`id`, P.`kf_users`, P.`id` FROM users U LEFT JOIN projects_users P ON U.`id` = P.`kf_users` WHERE U.`id` = $id) But it still won't give any results if I use the original query I posted above.

Comment: @Rylan Dirksen: Adding a LEFT JOIN does not remove rows. There must be an error. Are you sending the query from PHP? Did you inspect the return value of mysql_query and (if necessary) mysql_error? Can you post your exact code?

Comment: Thanks for helping me to rethink my query. I rebuilt it from scratch and discovered I was selecting from the wrong table.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I did wrong. I was joining from the users table before, which wasn't necessary since my PHP script already has the user ID.

Instead, I joined from the projects_users table and took out references to the users table:

```
SELECT S.*
    FROM projects_users P
    LEFT JOIN stream S ON P.`kf_projects` = S.`kf_projects`
    WHERE P.`kf_users` = '1';
```

...and it worked like a charm. Thanks all for your help!